# PHP: Load content dynamically based on the link clicked on the previous page?

Tags: php, dynamic, session

I've been Google-ing this for the past 24 hours, pretty much. I can't seem to find an answer that fits my scenario, even though I know it's widely used.

I have many links on one page (let's call it "page 1") of my website and I would like to them all to head to one, blank page (and this "page 2") and then have the content dynamically load, depending on what link was clicked on the previous page.

All I know is that I need to be able to set a PHP variable with the hyperlinks on page 1 and use some kind of `if(isset($_SESSION['phpVariable'])){ include('path/content.fileExt')}` on page 2 page so that it's ready to receive the variable and load the content accordingly.

I just have no clue how to do this, as I only started learning PHP yesterday. Help? :( :L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `$_GET[]` variable. On page1, the links could be to `page2?food=bacon` or `page2?food=foo`. On page2, you could say...

```
if ($_GET['food']=='bacon')
{
  // Stuff here that prints what you want.
}
elsif ($_GET['food']=='foo')
{
  // Stuff here that prints what you want.
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! ^.^ I did read somewhere that any variable that doesn't use $_SESSION is unsecure, though. Is this true?

Comment: The `$_GET[]` variable passes the information in the URL, so you wouldn't want to pass information such as a password along using get.

Comment: So should I be learning the more secure method from the start? Y'know, as good practise?

Comment: For this, the `$_SESSION[]` wouldn't work unless you used ajax, so I would use `$_GET[]`. For setting variables that need to be accessed by other pages though, using `$_SESSION[]` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an identifier of the content to be loaded through the URL.

Ex:
Set a value for one of the `GET` parameter to be the identifier for the content of page 2

`<a href="page2.php?pageid=content">Link to Page 2</a>`

And then in page 2 just check for the value and load the content accordingly.

```
include_once 'content/' . $_GET['pageid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

www.example.com/index.php?page=something_here

```
$_get["page"]
```

Would return "something_here"